# Из-за чего элементы добавляются в map не в том порядке?

Tags: java, map, hashmap

Делаю сериализатор/десериализатор для `Json` и возникла проблема с добавлением элементов в `Map`.
Конкретнее: Элементы добавляются не в том порядке в каком мне нужно, т.е. я добавляю `id`, а потом `name` и `owner`, но на выходе я получаю `owner`, `name`, `id`. Из-за чего такое происходит и как можно это решить? Код добавления элементов в `Map` ниже

```
        public Map<String, Object> serialize() {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("id", id);
            map.put("name", name);
            map.put("owner", owner);
            System.out.println(map);
            return map;
        }
```

На выходе я получаю это `{owner=LOVEC, name=Test, id=1}`

Comment: Кладите в обратном порядке, в чем проблема))))

Comment: @AVRamones не важно как класть, упадет одинаково в любом случае. HashMap меняет порядок или вернее не гарантирует его вовсе

Comment: HashMap использует hashCode() для того что-бы вычеслить индекс, поэтому в зависимости от результата hashCode() будет вычеслен идекс во внутреннем масиве, поэтому порядок элементов в нем не обеспечивается.

Comment: @AVRamones гений мысли конечно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HashMap не сохраняет порядок элементов. Если нужно сохранять порядок используйте [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). Там значения хранятся в порядке вставки.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ свыше ясен конечно, но рекомендую [LinkedMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LinkedMap.html). Он немного [другой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192706/java-is-there-a-container-which-effectively-combines-hashmap-and-arraylist) двусвязный

> LinkedHashMap is almost right, in that it keeps an iterable list, but
> it is unfortunately a linked list... retrieving the Nth element
> requires iterating from 1 to N.